# checking conditions on char * filename

Tags: c++

I want to give the user the option to specify one file (here it is `ground_truth_filename`). If he does not specify the option, I want to make assumptions on the default filename.

However, I am not able to check if the `ground_truth_filename` is `NULL` or zero even though I initialized it as `0` in the main program. If the argument is passed by user I assign `ground_truth_filename` to that argument. But the check `ground_truth_filename == 0` gives me an assert error.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
int processFile(const char *filename, 
                YAML::Emitter &out_yaml, 
                char *ground_truth_filename)
{   
    std::cout << "Here" << std::endl;

    if (ground_truth_filename == 0)
        sprintf(ground_truth_filename,"%s.yaml",filename);        

    std::ifstream imgstrm(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

    if (imgstrm.bad() || !imgstrm.is_open())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: %s\n", filename);
        return FILE_ERROR;
    }

    // get ground truth
    std::ifstream ground_truth_stream(ground_truth_filename);

    if (!ground_truth_stream.is_open()) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: %s\n", ground_truth_filename);
        return FILE_ERROR;
    }
}
```

Here is how the function is called. Perhaps I should initialize ground_truth_filename = '\0'?

```
char *ground_truth_filename = 0;
for (int i = 1; i + 1 < argc; i += 2) {
            if (!strcmp(argv[i], "--snapshot-markup")) {
                ground_truth_filename = argv[i + 1];
                markupFlag = true;
            }
        }
processFile(filename, out_yaml, ground_truth_filename)
```

Comment: `if (pointer == NULL) { sprintf(pointer, "foo"); }` is certainly wrong.

Comment: `if (NULL != ground_truth_filename && '\0' == *ground_truth_filename)`

Comment: What is the logic for NULL != ground_truth_filename && '\0' == *ground_truth_filename?

Comment: Could you post your call where `ground_truth_filename` is NULL (or zero). Calling `sprintf(NULL, ...)` is definitely a bad thing, so you probably shouldn't do that.

Comment: `sprintf(ground_truth_filename,"%s.yaml",filename);` ground_truth_filename points to `NULL`, `sprintf(...)` requires ground_truth_filename to be a buffer, it does not allocate for you.

Comment: DoSparKot's proposal was for if you wanted to use "" as the flag value for default, instead of NULL.

Comment: I think you need to show us how you call this function. I suspect there's more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: I added my function call above.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `sprintf` must be a pointer to a buffer large enough to hold the output.  A `NULL` pointer or a pointer to a smaller char buffer (e.g. the string literal "") will cause a crash.

Code that would work is:

```
char buf[256];

if (ground_truth_filename == NULL) {
   int charsneeded = snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"%s.yaml",filename);
   if (charsneeded >= sizeof(buf)) {
     return FILE_ERROR; // filename too long
   }
   ground_truth_filename = buf;
}
```

The point is that `buf` gives the new `filename` a place in memory to live.  Strings need that.

Edit: added the charsneeded thing to protect you from too-long filenames as a safety measure.  If you actually expect to need it, dynamically allocate buf instead.

Comment: And if `ground_truth_filename` is used outside of this function, after it returns, your code will ensure that it will point to who-knows what. Hilarity ensues.

Comment: @NikBougalis No it won't, because function parameters are local variables.  Touching what it *points to* is dangerous, but changes to the pointer itself stop mattering once the pointer disappears from the shrinking stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate ground_truth_filename before you can copy characters into it.

```
 if (ground_truth_filename == 0)
  {
    int length = strlen(filename) + strlen(".yaml") + 1;
    ground_truth_filename = new char[length];
    sprintf(ground_truth_filename,"%s.yaml",filename);   
  }
```

Comment: Without knowing what `filename` and `ground_truth_filename` are passed in as and what they are supposed to be upon return (both very unclear from the original post) it's difficult to say if this code will help.

Comment: Nik, I added my call above as well.

Comment: The answer by dspeyer below will solve your issue. Basically you are trying to `sprintf` something into a NULL buffer. This answer will too, but it requires you to remember whether you called `new[]` and if so to call `delete[]` before returning to avoid a memory leak. Is there a reason you don't use `std::string`?

Comment: how do I allocate argv[i+1] that is char* to a std:string? ground_truth_filename = argv[i + 1];